# Query not working properly using the pluck() method

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8, laravel-5.7

My query is not properly working; this query only gets data from one table. However, I should be able to take data from both tables. I'm using the `pluck()` method.

```php
$this->projectcosts = ProjectCost::where('project_id', $id)
    ->get()->pluck('costItems')->toArray();
```

Comment: The title should be used for a short description of the issue. The body of the question should contain: detailed description of issue, code, and explanation of what is expected.

Comment: i should be get data main table and relation table but this query show only one table data

Comment: You should use `with('relation')`  to essentially append the relation model to the main object, because as of right now it doesn't exist or hasn't been appended to the main object.

Comment: sir, with function  is not work ,i used with() function   but show internal Server  error